# When using List Validation, Add list entry works but not Edit when using Created date

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, 2016, validation, date

ISSUE: The list validation works when adding a list entry, but when editing the same entry (with no change), the user message is displayed. Using SharePoint 2016.

I have tried numerous combinations, including not using DateDif. I'm not 100% on why it seems to prefer logic for creating a new entry (created=modified) vs an edit. I assume because created time needs to be ignored.  The dates are date-only, but I did change them to date-time for some testing.  The time is all 12:00:00.

User Message: The End Date cannot be less than the Begin Date AND the End Date cannot exceed 366 days from the Begin Date AND Begin Date cannot be < Created date AND Begin Date cannot exceed 60 days beyond the created date.

```
=AND([Begin Date]<=[End Date],

IF([Begin Date]<=[End Date],DATEDIF([Begin Date],[End Date],"d")<=366,TRUE),

OR(
AND(Created=Modified,
IF(DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),DAY(Created))>[Begin Date],FALSE,
    DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),DAY(Created)),[Begin Date],"d")+1>0
    )
         ),
AND(Created<>Modified,
IF(Created>[Begin Date]+1,FALSE,
     DATEDIF(Created,[Begin Date]+1,"d")>0
   )
        )
    ),
OR(
AND(Created=Modified,
IF(DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),DAY(Created))>[Begin Date],FALSE,
    DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),DAY(Created)),[Begin Date]+1,"d")<60)
   ),
AND(Created<>Modified,
IF(Created>[Begin Date]+1,FALSE,
DATEDIF(Created,[Begin Date]+1,"d")<60
)
       )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue all hinges on comparing a date (without time) to the Created or Modified dates that have time.  To avoid the issue, add 1 day to the date without time and change the comparison operator accordingly.  In my case, the final validation formula is:

```
    =AND([Begin Date]<=[End Date],[End Date]<=[Begin Date]+366,[Begin Date]+1>Created,[Begin Date]+1<Created+60)
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.